# Visual Studio 2010 remote debugging is very slow (across domains, over VPN)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Overall debugging works, but each step through code takes dozens of seconds.

I've already closed all additional windows like stack trace, watches, autos; deleted all breakpoints.

The server and development machine are located in different domains, so I set up a local user on both, with a matching password. The remote debugger is running as a service.

Looking at the security log, I found quite a lot of entries about remote debugging account logging in (record about every minute).

Any suggestions on how I can speed up remote debugging?

- Development computer: quad core, 8 GB memory, Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.
- Target server: ASP.NET website, 2x dual core [Xeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon), 2 GB memory, remote debugger 2010.
- Communication channel: VPN, 5 Mbit/s, latency about 20 ms. (it seems that debugging never uses more than 20 kbyte/s)

Comment: I'm seeing this too. I've got a fast VPN connection, fast enough that doing remote desktop to the server runs like a champ.  But remote debugging is unusable.  5+ seconds to do a simple "Step Over".

Answer (score 1):

First identify the overall response times. It may be a little bit low level, but get [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) and monitor communication between both servers. That way you will know if debugging is slow because of your network and will give you a starting point.

Turn off active mode, else you may raise a few alarms in your network. I used it to debug communication between our WFE and a FAST query server, and we detected where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by an overactive firewall.

If you can, just to test, disable your firewall on both boxes and see if your performance increases at all.